# is there any difference between "Set<String> ss1 = new HashSet<>(m1.keySet());" and "Set<String> ss2 = m1.keySet();"

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, set

I'm learning Java Map interface and want to create an Set from Map 's key values. I have came up with two version of the code, they appears to be exactly the same to me. I was just wondering if there is any actually difference between them and when should I use one version over the other? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
    Map<String, Integer> m1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    m1.put("one", 1);
    m1.put("two", 2);
    m1.put("three", 3);

    //Version 1
    Set<String> ss1 = new HashSet<>(m1.keySet());

    //version 2
    Set<String> ss2 = m1.keySet();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference.  `ss2` cannot have elements added to it, but if you remove elements from `ss2` those keys will be correspondingly removed from the map.

`ss1` has an independent existence from `m1` and you can add and remove elements freely from it without affecting `m1`, though it also incurs O(n) overhead to do the copy.

Comment: The second sentence is slightly misleading. ss2 can have elements added to it, just not by doing ss2.add

Comment: @PaulBoddington could you please elaborate a little bit on what you said? Thank you very much!

Comment: @PaulBoddington It would be great if you could make an edit, elaborating on the comment.

Comment: Found what @PaulBoddington was talking about. Since the `keySet()` function returns a view and not a clone, it supports delete, etc. that directly affects the map. But, add/addAll are not supported. [[REFERENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29)]